# How to Draw dynamic polygons by user - once the map is generated from a fusion table?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I searched about fusion tables documentation, but i didn't find how to draw a polygon by the user dynamically once the map is generated by using fusion tables.
Can any one please help me regarding this.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawing

Comment: @user3508580 :Also have a look at the following link. It will help you too https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools

Answer (score 1):

The fusion tables layer is just a type of overlay. You create a map, you draw whatever overlays you need (including fusion tables, traffic layer, weather, etc) and this doesn't affect the map's capabilities to draw polygons, markers or more overlays, which you can do with the proper constructor

```
var newpolygon=new google.maps.Polygon({map:yourmapobject, path:pathobject});
```